# ¿Como guardar información 'cruda' constante en tu programa?

Tags: c, imagen, manejo-de-memoria, opengl, memoria

Estaba investigando como optimizar un programa que escribí con OpenGL en C, cuando me topé con [esto](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear/blob/d9ddd1810f8e43911c06f4f86eab3053db757adc/src/nuklear_font.c#L578), que, como creo deducir, es la información de los 'glyphs' de una tipografía o la tipografía en si, pero ya definida dentro del programa. Por poner otro ejemplo, me topé con [esto](https://github.com/vallentin/glText/blob/8200fa70e32acec0a3cd777d404f41ee0c203ca4/gltext.h#L1032) también, que es practicamente lo mismo, pero en otra librería. Por poner otro ejemplo más; Go tiene un [programa en el go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XN6x3L23Vok) el cual lee una imagén y la muestra por pantalla, a partir de una array de bytes.

Pues mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo hacer esto? ¿Como puedo definir una imagen, un archivo de tipografías o cualquier otro tipo de archivo dentro de mi programa como una array constante?

## Por ser más preciso:

```c
// La información de la imagen, ya definida en código.
const int imagen_w = 512, imagen_h = 512; // tamaño de la imagen en píxeles
const unsigned char imagen[] = // la imágen, predefinida.
{
    // información de la imágen
}

int main() 
{
    // manejo de la ventana de OpenGL...
    
    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexImage2D( // creación de la textura con la información predefinida.
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
        0,
        GL_RGBA8,
        imagen_w, 
        imagen_h,
        0,
        GL_RGBA, 
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
        imagen // información predefinida
    );
 
    // generación de parámetros de la textura y mipmap.

    while(window_is_running(wnd))
    {
        // renderizado
    }
    
    // destructores y liberación de memoría.

    return 0;
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer esto en OpenGL y en C?

## Edit:

Precisamente, me refiero al proceso de leer la información, probablemente con `fwrite`, y después de haberla leído, copiarla en una array constante, para que en la próxima ejecución, no haga falta volver a leerla.

**Nota:** Anteriormente, cité Go, para dejar claro a lo que me refiero con: "guardar informacion cruda, constante", no porque quiera implementarlo en Go.

Comment: No entiendo que estás preguntando, cuando tu mismo te estás respondiendo: `... como una array constante`. Pues eso mismo, un `const ALGO[ ] = { AA, BB, CC, ... };`

Comment: Me refiero, leer una imagen, copiar la información de la misma y guardarla en el programa, sin tener que volver a leerla de nuevo, por poner un ejemplo. Y me refiero, concretamente,  al proceso de leer la información de manera que la pueda copiar y dejarla en un array predefinida.

Comment: Ah, vale. Pues sencillo: o te buscas alguna herramienta que lo haga por ti, o te haces tu *a mano* una utilidad para ello :-)

Comment: Puedes usar cualquier programa de *hex dump* para convertir un archivo en la cadena de  dígitos hexadecimales y importarla a tu editor de texto. Por ejemplo, `hexdump -v -e '16/1 "0x%x," "\n"' tu-archivo.bin`